# What happened when the cherry juice turned blue?

Tags: organic-chemistry

When I was eating cherries today, some of its juice spilled on my shirt. Attempting to clean it, I poured a solution (baking soda, vinegar, toothpaste, and salt) onto the fabric. Though it did not remove the stain, the colour turned from a wine red to a subtle blue.

So the Question is: Why did it happen?

(This is not that technical so I'm not sure how to classify it)

Comment: After adding baking soda, I guess? Juice is acidic, but if enough base is added it may act as pH indicator and change color.

Comment: There are many naturally occurring pH indicators. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PH_indicator#Naturally_occurring_pH_indicators . BTW, red cabbage goes through the whole spectrum from very acid to alkaline!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cherries, like red cabbage, hibiscus and many red or purple colored fruits, contain a class of compounds called anthocyanins of general formula:

[image]

where $\ce{R_x}$ is either $\ce{OH}$, $\ce{OR}$ or $\ce{H}$.
In basic medium it loses a proton and it converts to a non charged chinone like structure, which has a blue color.